# jQM listview('refresh'); is breaking inset lists

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I can't seem to find out why this is happening: I have an unordered list in jQuery Mobile with `data-inset="true"` and when it first renders it looks perfectly fine with the rounded top and bottom. However, after dynamically adding new elements to the list and calling `listview('refresh')` on it, it renders as a non-inset list.

**Update:** This only happens when calling `listview('refresh');` on a list that is not on the currently active page. When you go to the page with the list on it, the listview is updated with all styles relevant to an inset list EXCEPT for the rounded corners on the top and bottom. To reproduce this error use this: http://jsfiddle.net/94X7S/10/

Here is what the HTML in the list looks like BEFORE calling `.listview('refresh');`

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-divider-theme="b" class="ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
    <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading" class="ui-li ui-li-divider ui-btn ui-bar-b ui-corner-top ui-btn-up-undefined">
        User Reviews (4) <span class="rate"><img src="..." alt="Rating"/></span>
    </li>
    <li data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li">
        <div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="ui-btn-text">
                <a href="#reviews" class="ui-link-inherit">
                    <h3 class="ui-li-heading"><img src="..." alt="Rating"/>Review Title</h3>
                    <p class="ui-li-desc">Review Content...</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow"/>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li ui-corner-bottom">
        <div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="ui-btn-text">
                <a href="#reviews" class="ui-link-inherit">
                    <h3 class="ui-li-heading"><img src="..." alt="Rating"/>Review Title</h3>
                    <p class="ui-li-desc">Review Content...</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow"/>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And here is what the HTML in the list looks like AFTER calling `.listview('refresh');`
<

```
ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-divider-theme="b" class="ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
    <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading" class="ui-li ui-li-divider ui-btn ui-bar-b">
        User Reviews (4) <span class="rate"><img src="..." alt="Rating"/></span>
    </li>
    <li data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li">
        <div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="ui-btn-text">
                <a href="#reviews" class="ui-link-inherit">
                    <h3 class="ui-li-heading"><img src="..." alt="Rating"/>Review Title</h3>
                    <p class="ui-li-desc">Review Content...</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow"/>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li">
        <div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="ui-btn-text">
                <a href="#reviews" class="ui-link-inherit">
                    <h3 class="ui-li-heading"><img src="..." alt="Rating"/>Review Title</h3>
                    <p class="ui-li-desc">Review Content...</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow"/>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Notice that some of the classes on the first and last `<li>` are missing after the `listview('refresh');` - is there a reason this is happening or something that can be done to prevent this from happening? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems to work in an isolated instance: http://jsfiddle.net/94X7S/1/

Comment: You can reproduce the problem using this quick and dirty example:
http://jsfiddle.net/94X7S/5/
Click on "Add Item" then click on "Page 2" and you will see the inset goes away.

Comment: If you click "Add" then go to "Page 2" you will see the insert dissapears like in the above example, however if you hit refresh, the inset will reappear. It seems like if the page isn't active, when you refresh the list it doesn't include the data-inset. 
http://jsfiddle.net/94X7S/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what you mean when navigating to the second page. A work-around would be to only `refresh` the `listview` elements when the page they are on is actually shown:

```
$('.add').click( function(){

    //you can combine selectors by adding a comma in-between them
    $('#1, #2').append('<li>' + count + '</li>');

    //refresh the listview on the current page (if it exists)
    $(this).closest('.ui-content').find('.ui-listview').listview('refresh');

    count++;
});

$('[data-role="page"]').bind('pageshow', function () {

    //refresh the listview on the current page (if it exists)
    $(this).find('.ui-listview').listview('refresh');
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/94X7S/12/

Comment: Though this is just a workaround - it should probably be fixed. I will let the JQM Team know that the rounded-corner classes aren't added (It seems all of the other Inset Classes are added) when listview('refresh'); is called for a list on an inactive page.

Comment: It seems to me to be a better UX design to only update the lists on the current page (why do work when it may not be seen?). This may be a feature and not a bug.

Comment: I think it is a bug though since it DOES do the refresh, the ONLY thing missing from the refresh is the classes "ui-corner-top" and "ui-corner-bottom". And the refresh works just fine if the list doesn't have data-inset="true". Also, the refresh works fine on inactive pages for all other components except for inset listviews.